# How to limit a Github Action to fire only once on a release trigger?

Tags: github-actions

I need to run a Github Action upon any change that happens to my repo releases: creating draft/release/prerelease, editing, deleting, etc. Currently I'm using this code:

```
name: Test

on:
  release:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs: 
  //... jobs
```

However, upon creating let's say a prerelease, action is triggered 3 times: for prereleasing, creating and publishing:
[image: Example]

How do I limit this Github Action to fire only once per "user interaction"?

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#release

It seems you need to specify activity types.

```yaml
on:
  release:
    types: [prereleased]
```

---

Edited:

> However, the issue is that I need an action to run not only on just prerelease, but also on basically any change of releases section

How about looking at individual events within it?

```yaml
name: Test

on:
  release:

jobs:
  foo:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: "This step will be executed only when it is prereleased"
        run: echo 1
        if: github.event.release.prereleased == true
      - name: "This step will be executed when it is not prereleased"
        run: echo 2
        if: github.event.release.prereleased == false
```

Comment: However, the issue is that I need an action to run not only on just prerelease, but also on basically any change of releases section

Comment: I might not have understood what you wanted to do correctly, but I have added another method for now.